# Clarification of a special case of the multi-variable chain rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Reading through a proof in my multi-variable calculus (Vector Calculus, p.154) notes I encounter a problem.

It states:

Suppose $c:\Bbb  R \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ is a differentiable path and $f: \Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R$. Let $h(t) = f(c(t)) = f(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. Then
$$\frac {dh}{dt}(t_o) = \lim_{t\to t_0} \frac {h(t)-h(t_0)}{t-t_0}$$

The author then states:

$$\frac {h(t) - h(t_0))} {t-t_0} = \frac {f(x(t),y(t),z(t))-f(x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t_0))} {t-t_0}$$

**(this next equality is what I do not understand)

$$=\frac {f(x(t),y(t),z(t))-f(x(t_0),y(t),z(t))} {t-t_0} + \frac {f(x(t_0),y(t),z(t))-f(x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t))} {t-t_0}+\frac {f(x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t))-f(x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t_0))} {t-t_0}$$

It seems the author is changing one component at a time from each of the quotients in the above expression but I am not sure why this is true. Any clarifications or insights much appreciated.

Comment: Is the first term in the second fraction really $x(t)$ vs. $x(t_0)$?

Comment: @dxiv you are correct, edited...

Comment: Then you answered your own question. If you add up the numerators the newly inserted terms cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully the terms added and subtracted all cancel out.